# problem with templates in custom module

Tags: theming

I wrote a simple module that uses `hook_theme()`.

```
/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function test_theme() {
  'upload_page' => array(
  'template' => 'templates/upload_page',
  'arguments' => array(
    'uploadurl' => NULL,
    'options' => NULL,
    'title' => NULL,
    'user' => NULL),
   )
}
```

I still have an error.

> Warning: include(./sites/all/themes/test/templates/upload_page.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

How do I change this path to ./sites/all/modules/test/templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal won't look for the template in a theme path unless

1. You've added this code to a *theme* instead of a *module* or
2. You've put your module in the theme folder instead of sites/all/modules, and then perhaps moved it once installed (less likely I think).

If you've done either of these I'd advise fixing that problem and putting the code/module where it's supposed to go.

If you're too invested at this point, though, you can use the `path` argument to [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_theme/6) to provide a static path to your theme's implementation folder:

```
'upload_page' => array(
  'template' => 'templates/upload_page',
  'arguments' => array(
    'uploadurl' => NULL,
    'options' => NULL,
    'title' => NULL,
    'user' => NULL
  ),
  'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'test')
)
```

The docs I've linked to are for Drupal 6 as I assume from your code that's what you're using; if you're using Drupal 7, the `arguments` property should be changed to `variables`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I haven't added my code to theme but to module and I haven't moved this code after install.

It is possible that it happens because I have theme on the same name what module is?